# Create table in c# with values from database

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am creating an application for my coursework but there is one thing I cannot figure out how to complete. This is I need to create a table in winforms with data from a database.

The table needs to have days of week on columns and times on rows. I wan't to get the data from a database and fill in the table. This table is for patient appointments in a doctors surgery.

Comment: google database 101 and start from there

Comment: possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483320/c-bind-datagridview-to-a-database-file-in-the-application-directory

Comment: U can fill a datatable from your database, and then, U can use this datatable like a List

Comment: This one thing is quite large.  Do you already have the database made?  If not then that's one large topic.  Once you have it, you need to connect to it in code, query for data, and then get that data into a DataTable...3 more topics.  This is far too much for a single SO question, hence the snarky replies.  If this is a single assignment, and you don't already have at least some of these skills, then shame on your instructor.

Comment: 16 questions, 13 answers but not a one accepted.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to understand how SO works. probably help avoid those debilitating DVs too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to focus on your SQL Server database first, then your C# form second.

Setup your table so it has a form similar to this:

```
 select 
 getdate() as Curr_Date
,datename(dw,getdate()) as Weekday_Name
,datepart(dw,getdate()) as Weekday_Number
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 1 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Sunday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Monday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 3 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Tuesday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 4 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Wednesday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 5 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Thursday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 6 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Friday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 7 then 'Your Column Value Goes Here' end as Saturday
```

You will replace `getdate()` with the actual timestamp of your true data.
You will replace `'Your Column Value Goes Here'` with the actual value of your data.
Lastly, you will want your C# form to capture the specific cells.

I just read your post again.  It looks like you want the time in the row?  If so, try something like this:

```
 select 
 getdate() as Curr_Date
,datename(dw,getdate()) as Weekday_Name
,datepart(dw,getdate()) as Weekday_Number
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 1 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Sunday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Monday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 3 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Tuesday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 4 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Wednesday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 5 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Thursday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 6 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Friday
,case when datepart(dw,getdate()) = 7 then cast(getdate() as time) end as Saturday
```

Because I'm feeling generous and actually enjoy writing SQL...

```
create table Schedule 
(
 Person varchar(15)
,Appointment datetime
)
;
insert into Schedule values
('John Doe','2017-11-20 9:25:00'),
('Jane Doe','2017-11-22 9:15:00'),
('Michael','2017-11-24 9:25:00'),
('Sam','2017-11-26 9:15:00')
;

create table Time_Table 
(
Start_Time time,
End_Time time,
Time_Name Varchar(20)
)
;
insert into Time_Table values 
 ('9:00' , '9:10'  , '9:10 - 9:10'  )
,('9:10' , '9:20'  , '9:10 - 9:20'  )
,('9:20' , '9:30'  , '9:20 - 9:30'  )
,('9:30' , '9:40'  , '9:30 - 9:40'  )
,('9:40' , '9:50'  , '9:40 - 9:50'  )
,('9:50' , '10:00' , '9:50 - 10:00' )
;

 select 
 a.Time_Name
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 1 then b.Person end) as Sunday
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 2 then b.Person end) as Monday
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 3 then b.Person end) as Tuesday
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 4 then b.Person end) as Wednesday
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 5 then b.Person end) as Thursday
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 6 then b.Person end) as Friday
,max(case when datepart(dw,b.Appointment) = 7 then b.Person end) as Saturday
from Time_Table a 
LEFT JOIN Schedule b ON cast(b.Appointment as time) between a.Start_Time and a.End_Time
group by
a.Time_Name
order by a.Time_Name
```

This is the SQL Server version of your assignment.  The point of your assignment clearly has more to do with learning the fundamentals of interacting with databases.  I am not going to build a CRUD app for you on here, but this should at least give you a very solid foundation to start from.

Comment: This doesn't create the results I hoped. When I run the query all I get is a single row with the current date and day. Nothing based on my data.

Comment: This is an image of what I want: https://storage.marks.pw/index.php/s/opeensLmHWA22rn

Comment: Correct.  I'm not sure where you want to spend your time working (SQL Server or C#).  What I gave you assumes you already have the data stored.  as a table with a Column1 as a Timestamp and Column2 as a Value (eg Name).  Since this is a homework problem, you should really get back to studying.  Your post has been down-voted multiple times already.  Honestly, I'm not sure why it hasn't been closed yet.  Good luck in your studies.